# How to add a prefix to a WordPress post preview url?

Tags: plugins, php, cloudflare

I need to remove any query parameters from the WordPress post preview URL.

I need to access `https://www.domain.com/prefix/12345` and see the same post preview I would see on `https://www.domain.com/?p=12345&preview=true`

It can not redirect, the URL in the browser must still be `https://www.domain.com/prefix/12345`

As an alternative, adding a prefix to the original WordPress post preview url would also be enough:
`https://www.domain.com/previx/?p=12345&preview=true`

How can I achieve one of these without changing the URLs of the published posts?

The motivations is that I need a URL with a prefix to create a bypass **route** on CloudFlare **Workers**.

ps.: Cloudflare Page rules are different than Cloudflare Workers Routes. The Worker Routes does not support query parameters on it.

Comment: It might be simpler to just view preview pages on the origin server, not through CloudFlare.

Comment: Are you asking how to get WordPress to generate the preview URLs in the new format, or accept the new format, or both?

Comment: There's a simple rule to fix that with Cloudflare, https://onlinemediamasters.com/cloudflare-page-rules-for-wordpress/#dont-cache-preview-pages you shouldn't need to modify WP

Comment: @TomJNowell, the link you sent refers to Cloudflare Page Rules. I am talking about the Cloudflare Workers Routes. I replaced the term 'rule' by route in the question.

Comment: @Rup, I need both. I need to have the post preview to use a prefix so that I can create a Cloudflare Worker Route excluding it. Cloudflare workers does not support routes containing ```?``` or query parameters. https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/routes